# Filter dataframe based on 2 columns with values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

| country | values |
| --- | --- |
| BG | 20 |
| BG | 4 |
| BG | 3 |
| BG | -3 |
| BG | -20 |
| DE | 20 |
| DE | 3 |
| DE | -20 |
| IND | 20 |
| IND | -2 |
| GB | 30 |
| GB | 3 |
| GB | -30 |

I want to filter the dataframe in such a way that values from BG and GB should be < absolute (5) and all other countries should be < 5 such that the dataframe becomes

| country | values |
| --- | --- |
| BG | 4 |
| BG | 3 |
| BG | -3 |
| DE | 3 |
| DE | -20 |
| IND | -2 |
| GB | 3 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a mask:

```
mask = (df['values'].mask(df['country'].isin(['BG', 'GB']), # if BG/GB
                          df['values'].abs())               # get abs
                    .lt(5)                                  # now is it < 5?
        )
df[mask]
```

output:

```
   country  values
1       BG       4
2       BG       3
3       BG      -3
6       DE       3
7       DE     -20
9      IND      -2
11      GB       3
```

##### alternative:  using explicit conditions

```
# is country GB or GB?
m1 = df['country'].isin(['BG', 'GB'])
# is abs(value) < 5?
m2 = df['values'].abs().lt(5)
# is value < 5?
m3 = df['values'].lt(5)

df[(m1&m2)|(~m1&m3)]   # for GB/BG get mask m2, else get mask m3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df[((df['country'].isin(['BG', 'GB']))&(df['values'].abs()<5))|((df['values']<5)&(~df['country'].isin(['BG', 'GB'])))]
```

Or more simply:

```
df[(~(df['country'].isin(['BG', 'GB']))&(df['values']<5))|(df['values'].abs()<5)]
```

Comment: that would filter out all countries other than GB/BG ;)

Comment: still incorrect, you bypass the country filter with the second mask. I'll update my answer to show you why